# cntlm: the request was denied

Tags: firewall

I have configured **CNTLM** server between users and **Windows TMG** firewall.

**CNTLM** configured with "allow all" - no any `ACL` or something like it:

```
Gateway yes

#
# Useful in Gateway mode to allow/restrict certain IPs
#
#Allow          127.0.0.1
#Deny           0/0
```

From Sun 05:25 (!) I got next errors in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Jan 19 05:25:50 teamcity cntlm[7923]: The request was denied!
Jan 19 05:26:25 teamcity cntlm[7923]: Connection accepted from 10.***.***.183:53717
```

And there is a lot of them:

```
# cat /var/log/messages | grep "10.***.***.183" | wc -l
64900
```

Eventually- server goes down with `"Virtual machine cpu usage"` alert.

What means here "`The request was denied`"? **Google** says only about `ACL` - but it's not configured here. Also - host `10.***.***.183` are "trusted" host of our developer and he often uses this proxy when his `Maven` download new artifacts in it's repository.

Comment: were you able to figure it out